# Codeigniter Multi File Upload with HTML5, can it be done with tools like Uploadify?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uploadify, codeigniter-2

Is it possible to do a multi file uploader using just HTML5 and PHP? I was hoping I could select multiple files, store them in a loop, and just iterate through all the files and upload them to the server.

But Codeigniter only uploads the first file I selected.

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
{
      $this->upload->do_upload($key['name'])
}
```

I have additional logic for handling stuff like upload path and file name, but that code is fine, but this loop seems to only work for the first select file and nothing else.

If it's not possible to use HTML5 and php, I will just use Uploadify, or is there a way to modify the Upload Class to support multi file uploads?

Here's my method more or less,

```
public function uploadScreens($id) {
$this->load->library('upload');
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
$config['max_size'] = '45000';
$config['max_width'] = '20000';
    $config['max_height'] = '15000';
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
    {
    if (!empty($key['name']))
            {
                $this->db->set('gameid', $id);
        $this->db->insert('gamescreens');
                $screenid = $this->db->insert_id();

                $this->createDirectory($screenid);
                $filename = $this->randomFilename();
                $config['file_name'] = "$filename";
                $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . "../content/gamescreens/" . $screenid . '/';
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload($key['name']))
                {
                    $data = $this->upload->data();
                    $sourceurl = $data["full_path"];
                    $this->db->simple_query("update gamescreens set source = '$sourceurl' Where id=$screenid");
        }
                else
                {
                    //catch eerrors
                }
            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code example, I see the following problem:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
{
      $this->upload->do_upload($key['name'])
}
```

I believe that should be `$value['name']`, not true?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't have to handle multiple files with CI when using uploadify. Because uploadify will upload the files (uploadify queue) one by one calling the controller action once per file.

I'm using this action in my upload controller to upload 10 image files

```
/**
 * Upload Action.
 */
public function upload()
{
    $targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {


        // Validate the file type
        $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
        $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

        $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
        $targetName = uniqid() . '.' . $fileParts['extension'];
        $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $targetName;

        if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
            echo $targetName;
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid file type.';
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my uploadify client side config

```
// create file uploader
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'swf'      : '/swf/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : YOUR_CONTROLLER + '/upload',
    'uploadLimit' : 10,
    'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
        // do stuff where a file is uploaded
    },
    'onQueueComplete' : function(data) {
        // do stuff when queue done
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue about CodeIgniter. To upload multiple file in CI, you need to call `$this->upload->initialize($config);` in loop.

Comment: I had it in the loop before, but it wouldn't do the multiple file upload. I've updated my code with my method.

Comment: I don't think so, I just select multiple file. And have one input tag in the view.

Answer (score 0):

i don use uplodify to upload multiple file

but i use [here](http://www.mitesdesign.com/blog/open-source/multi-upload-jquery-code-igniter)

and edit litlle about multi upload library 
and get some problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920579/code-igniter-multiple-file-uploads-just-displays-last-uploaded-file)

it can uppload multiple file but i dont know whats wrong with the 'upload file data' in succes from, it just show, 'data file uppload from last file uploaded'

i hope this will help you, if you can fix this problem let me know to