# Multiple file uploads just displays last uploaded file

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to build some application but have frustated in uploded code with ci, I used `multi_upload`.
I won upload some file and send them with email, but on CI `file_path` must be uploaded in server root so I try uploaded and find the `file_path`.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Upload extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{    
    $this->load->view('upload_form');
}

function do_upload()
{

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; // server directory
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; // by extension, will check for whether it is an image
    $config['max_size']    = '1000'; // in kb
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->load->library('Multi_upload');

    $files = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();

    if ( $files )        
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }    
    else
    {

        $data = array(
                'upload_data' =>$this->upload->data()


        );
        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}    
}
?>
```

my `upload_form`:

```
 <?php if (isset($error)) echo $error;?>
 <form action="http://localhost/hemmmm/index.php/upload/do_upload" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="userfile[]" size="20" class="multi"  
  data-ajax="false"><br /><br />

  <input type="submit" value="upload" />
```

My succes_form:

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
  <html>
   <head>
  <title>Upload Form</title>
     </head>
  <body>

    <h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>

  <ul>

   <?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
   <li><?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

 <p><?php echo anchor('upload', 'Upload More Files!'); ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

my multi_upload library :

```
     <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

/**

    * This library assumes that you have already loaded the default CI Upload Library seperately
    * 
    * Functions is based upon CI_Upload, Feel free to modify this 
    *   library to function as an extension to CI_Upload
    * 
    * Library modified by: Alvin Mites
    * http://www.mitesdesign.com
    * 
    */

class Multi_upload  {
    function Multi_upload () {
//      $CI =& get_instance();
    }

    /**
     * Perform multiple file uploads
     * Based upon JQuery Multiple Upload Class
     * see http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/
     */ 
    function go_upload($field = 'userfile') {
        $CI =& get_instance(); 
        // Is $_FILES[$field] set? If not, no reason to continue.
        if ( ! isset($_FILES[$field]['name'][0]))
        {
            $CI->upload->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
            return FALSE;
        } else
        {
            $num_files = count($_FILES[$field]['name']) -1;
            $file_list = array();
            $error_hold = array();
            $error_upload = FALSE;
        }

        // Is the upload path valid?
        if ( ! $CI->upload->validate_upload_path())
        {
            // errors will already be set by validate_upload_path() so just return FALSE
            return FALSE;
        }

        for ($i=0; $i < $num_files; $i++) {

//            $fname = $_FILES[$field]['name'][$i];
//            echo "$fname\n\n<br><br>\n\n";

            $error_hold[$i] = FALSE;

            // Was the file able to be uploaded? If not, determine the reason why.
            if ( ! is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i]))
            {
                $error = ( ! isset($_FILES[$field]['error'][$i])) ? 4 : $_FILES[$field]['error'][$i];

                switch($error)
                {
                    case 1:  // UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_exceeds_limit';
                        break;
                    case 2: // UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_exceeds_form_limit';
                        break;
                    case 3: // UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
                       $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_file_partial';
                        break;
                    case 4: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
                       $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_file_selected';
                        break;
                    case 6: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_temp_directory';
                        break;
                    case 7: // UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_unable_to_write_file';
                        break;
                    case 8: // UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_stopped_by_extension';
                        break;
                    default :
                        $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_no_file_selected';
                        break;
                }

                return FALSE;
            }

            // Set the uploaded data as class variables
            $CI->upload->file_temp = $_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'][$i];              
             $CI->upload->file_name = $this->_prep_filename($_FILES[$field]['name'][$i]);  
            $CI->upload->file_size = $_FILES[$field]['size'][$i];        
            $CI->upload->file_type = preg_replace("/^(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $_FILES[$field]['type'][$i]);
            $CI->upload->file_type = strtolower($CI->upload->file_type);
            $CI->upload->file_ext  = $CI->upload->get_extension($_FILES[$field]['name'][$i]);

            // Convert the file size to kilobytes
            if ($CI->upload->file_size > 0)
            {
                $CI->upload->file_size = round($CI->upload->file_size/1024, 2);
            }

            // Is the file type allowed to be uploaded?
            if ( ! $CI->upload->is_allowed_filetype())
            {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_filetype';
            }

            // Is the file size within the allowed maximum?
            if ( ! $CI->upload->is_allowed_filesize())
            {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_filesize';
            }

            // Are the image dimensions within the allowed size?
            // Note: This can fail if the server has an open_basdir restriction.
            if ( ! $CI->upload->is_allowed_dimensions())
            {
                $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_invalid_dimensions';
            }

            // Sanitize the file name for security
            $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->clean_file_name($CI->upload->file_name);

            // Remove white spaces in the name
            if ($CI->upload->remove_spaces == TRUE)
            {
                $CI->upload->file_name = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $CI->upload->file_name);
            }

            /*
             * Validate the file name
             * This function appends an number onto the end of
             * the file if one with the same name already exists.
             * If it returns false there was a problem.
             */
            $CI->upload->orig_name = $CI->upload->file_name;

            if ($CI->upload->overwrite == FALSE)
            {
                $CI->upload->file_name = $CI->upload->set_filename($CI->upload->upload_path, $CI->upload->file_name);

                if ($CI->upload->file_name === FALSE)
                {
                    $error_hold[$i] = TRUE;
                }
            }

            /*
             * Move the file to the final destination
             * To deal with different server configurations
             * we'll attempt to use copy() first.  If that fails
             * we'll use move_uploaded_file().  One of the two should
             * reliably work in most environments
             */
            if ( ! @copy($CI->upload->file_temp,     $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name))
            {
                if ( ! @move_uploaded_file($CI->upload->file_temp, $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name))
                {
                     $error_hold[$i] = 'upload_destination_error';
                }
            }

            /*
             * Run the file through the XSS hacking filter
             * This helps prevent malicious code from being
             * embedded within a file.  Scripts can easily
             * be disguised as images or other file types.
             */
            if ($CI->upload->xss_clean == TRUE)
            {
                $CI->upload->do_xss_clean();
            }

            if ($error_hold[$i]) {
                $error_upload = TRUE;

//                echo $error_hold[$i];
            } else {
                if ($imageVar = $this->multiple_image_properties($CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name)) {

                    $file_list[] = array(
                            'name' => $CI->upload->file_name,
                            'file' => $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name,
                            'size' => $CI->upload->file_size,
                            'ext' => $CI->upload->file_ext,
                            'image_type' => $imageVar->image_type,
                            'height' => $imageVar->height,
                            'width' => $imageVar->width
                            );
                } else {
                    $file_list[] = array(
                            'name' => $CI->upload->file_name,
                            'file' => $CI->upload->upload_path.$CI->upload->file_name,
                            'size' => $CI->upload->file_size,
                            'type' => $CI->upload->file_type,
                            'ext' => $CI->upload->file_ext,
                            );
                }
            }

// For debugging
/*            
            if (strlen($error_hold[$i]) > 1) {
                    print_r($error_hold);
            }
*/            
        } // end for loop

// Add error display for individual files        
        if ($error_upload) {
            $this->set_error($error_hold);
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return $file_list;
        }    
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Set Image Properties
     *
     * Uses GD to determine the width/height/type of image
     *
     * @access    public
     * @param    string
     * @return    void
     */    
    function multiple_image_properties($path = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance(); 
        if ( ! $CI->upload->is_image())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (function_exists('getimagesize'))
        {
            if (FALSE !== ($D = @getimagesize($path)))
            {    
                $types = array(1 => 'gif', 2 => 'jpeg', 3 => 'png');

                $image->width       = $D['0'];
                $image->height      = $D['1'];
                $image->image_type        = ( ! isset($types[$D['2']])) ? 'unknown' : $types[$D['2']];

                return $image;
            }
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Set an error message
     *
     * @access    public
     * @param    string
     * @return    void
     */    
    function set_error($msg)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();    
        $CI->lang->load('upload');

        if (is_array($msg))
        {
            foreach ($msg as $val)
            {
                $msg = ($CI->lang->line($val) == FALSE) ? $val : $CI->lang->line($val);                
                $this->error_msg[] = $msg;
                log_message('error', $msg);
            }        
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = ($CI->lang->line($msg) == FALSE) ? $msg : $CI->lang->line($msg);
            $this->error_msg[] = $msg;
            log_message('error', $msg);
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
 protected function _prep_filename($filename) {

        $CI = & get_instance();

        if (strpos($filename, '.') === FALSE OR $CI->upload->allowed_types == '*') {
            return $filename;
        }

        $parts = explode('.', $filename);
        $ext = array_pop($parts);
        $filename = array_shift($parts);

        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if (!in_array(strtolower($part), $CI->upload->allowed_types) OR $CI->upload->mimes_types(strtolower($part)) === FALSE) {
                $filename .= '.' . $part . '_';
            } else {
                $filename .= '.' . $part;
            }
        }

        $filename .= '.' . $ext;

        return $filename;
    }  

    }
?>
```

When I try to upload one file it works and I have great explaination about `upload_data`
but when I try to upload multiple files it works the file is uploaded, but just displays
status about last file uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

$file_list array is being overwritten every time it processes an image from the looks of it. Try incrementing that with the $i variable when it's being populated.

```
$file_list[$i] = array
```

Comment: i cant do that, i dont know where/what code must i typing, please geve me the code

Comment: cmon sir Rick if you know somethink please share your knowladge, i get insomnia to solve this problem just by my self

Comment: It's populating that array in the multiple upload function, cmon Frog, read your own code.

Comment: Agggggggghhhhh freeze....., i dont know what the meaning of that part library, its a plugin ci-jquery-multi-upload, and i am not pro about php code,,,, but thank you sir Rick for annswer my question ^_^